# Mongo run-rs does not run on Mac

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I get the following error when running run-rs on Mac M2 chipset. I had an Intel chipset with same version of node and it worked. Any ideas?

```
% run-rs -v 5.0.13 --shell
Purging database...
Running '/Users/mattkuhns/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/run-rs/5.0.13/mongod' [ 27017, 27018, 27019 ]
Starting replica set...
Error: spawn Unknown system error -86
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:412:11)
    at spawn (node:child_process:698:9)
    at /Users/mattkuhns/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/run-rs/node_modules/mongodb-topology-manager/lib/replset.js:94:18
    at Promise._execute (/Users/mattkuhns/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/run-rs/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:384:9)
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/Users/mattkuhns/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/run-rs/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:518:18)
    at new Promise (/Users/mattkuhns/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/run-rs/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:103:10)
    at ReplSet.discover (/Users/mattkuhns/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/run-rs/node_modules/mongodb-topology-manager/lib/replset.js:93:12)
    at /Users/mattkuhns/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/run-rs/node_modules/mongodb-topology-manager/lib/replset.js:159:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at onFulfilled (/Users/mattkuhns/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/run-rs/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)
    at /Users/mattkuhns/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/run-rs/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at co (/Users/mattkuhns/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/run-rs/node_modules/co/index.js:50:10)
    at /Users/mattkuhns/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/run-rs/node_modules/mongodb-topology-manager/lib/replset.js:146:7
    at Promise._execute (/Users/mattkuhns/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/run-rs/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:384:9)
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/Users/mattkuhns/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/run-rs/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:518:18)
```